# using jquery to read an Asp.net arraylist

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have a web method in ASP.net which it's output is an ArrayList and read cities from databse.
this web method is called using jquery.

```
$.ajax(
    { url: "../AjaxServices/StateCity.asmx/showcity",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        data: '{s: ' + $('#<%=DpState.ClientID%>').val() + '}',
        success: function(data) {
```

}

I wanna know how to loop through `data`, because the data is object.
I knew about

```
jQuery.each( collection, callback(indexInArray, valueOfElement) )
```

but doesn't work

Comment: Look at the response and the `data` parameter in Firebug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call an ASP.Net WebMethod using AJAX, it returns an object with a `d` property containing your data.

If your WebMethod returns a collection, you can write

```
$.each(data.d, function(index, obj) { ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

Slaks answer is great a ndI found a solution base on SLaks answer, so I'll share it here:
just take care about `Value` and `Text` they're case sensitive.

```
success: function(data) { 
                $.each(data.d, function() {   
                  alert(this['Value'] + ':' + this['Text']);                 })             }
```